# MVC 4: Custom Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

ASP.NET MVC 4 website.

Got a database-table named "Locations", which holds only three possible Locations (eg. "CA","NY","AT")
The default route would be:

```
http://server/Location/  --- list of Locations
http://server/Location/NY --- details of NY-Location
```

How can I create a custom route without the /Location/ - bit?
(which I find a bit more nice)

So that

```
http://server/NY - details of NY
http://server/AT - details of AT
.... etc...
```

and

```
http://server/Location  --- list of Locations
```

Comment: set it in the controller? Inside the controller you have to specify the route and then the function that comes with it, right? so set the route to for `server/{city}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to do a custom route using a route constraint:
(the order matters)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "City",
    url: "{city}",
    constraints: new { city = @"\w{2}" },
    defaults: new { controller = "Location", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

with the matching controller:

```
public class LocationController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Location/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /{city}
    public ActionResult Details(string city)
    {
        return View(model:city);
    }
}
```

If you want to allow only NY, CA and AT you could write you route constraint like:

```
constraints: new { city = @"NY|CA|AT" }
```

(lower case works too). Another, more generic solution instead of using a route contraint is to implement your own `IRouteConstraint`. Se [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570237/mvc-3-routing-help-with-dynamic-route/7570543#7570543).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to specify the route inside your controller. Look at this tutorial on how to specify route constraints:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

> You use route constraints to restrict the browser requests that match
>   a particular route. You can use a regular expression to specify a
>   route constraint.

Also look at this post: [How to map a route for /News/5 to my news controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332026/asp-net-mvc-4-route-news-5)