# Regular Expression in routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to use regular expression to add rules in routing in mvc4. I want to add some validation rules to my route. I am using asp.net mvc4 application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 4: Custom Route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518388/mvc-4-custom-route)

Answer (score 0):

Thing you are looking for is called `Constraint` for route. You specify the constraint to your route definition as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "somthing",
url: "{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);
```